# cocos2d moving objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to move an object around the screen like in the game geometry wars.  I can rotate the object just fine, however I cant seem to get it to move based on the direction it is facing.  I have this code here which i think is right for doing this but I keep getting syntax errors:

```
spriteObject.x = spriteObject.x + speed*cos(Angle)
spriteObject.y = spriteObject.y + speed*sin(Angle)
```

The errors are 'request for member x not in struct or union.'  How do you do this in Objective-c/cocos2d syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://cocos2d.org/doc/api/cocos-module.html) for the [sprite class](http://cocos2d.org/doc/api/cocos.sprite.Sprite-class.html), you would need to do the following:

```
float angle = spriteObject.rotation
spriteObject.position.x = spriteObject.position.x + speed*cos(angle)
spriteObject.position.y = spriteObject.position.y + speed*sin(angle)
```

**edit** (in response to comment):

I see that you are programming for the iPhone, which means you need to be using the *iphone* cocos2d library, and **not the one I linked to before**.

The syntax will be different, as will the example code, since the iPhone version uses the Objective-C langugage, whereas the original cocos2d uses Python.

Google code has good documentation on the iPhone version of cocos2d, including [sample code](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:hello_actions).

Based on that sample code, you will have to do the following:

```
float newX = spriteObject.position.x + speed * cos(angle);
float newY = spriteObject.position.y + speed * sin(angle);
spriteObject.position =  ccp( newX, newY );
```

Comment: using that gives me the same errors...
spriteObject.position.x = spriteObject.x + speed*cos(Angle)
spriteObject.position.y = spriteObject.y + speed*sin(Angle)